# How to change the workspace in android?

Tags: android, eclipse

My current workspace is in D drive I want to change my workspace and create a new workspace in C drive.How can I change the workspace in android?

Comment: There is no "workspace" in Android. I am assuming you are referring to Eclipse.

Comment: To accept an answer, click on the green checkmark next to an answer that you want to accept as the "best answer" to your question. That will reward people who help you and help you get better answers in the future.

Comment: After having switched the workspace (see NickT or JasCav answer) you may want to import existing code: File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace -> Next -> Browse to folder with project -> copy into workspace if necessary -> Finish

Answer (score 13):

To change your workspace in Eclipse (as there is not a "workspace" for Android), open up Eclipse and select:

> File > Switch Workspace > Other...

Then, select your new workspace location. You can copy settings from your current workspace if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Create a folder anywhere you like using explorer.

Then from Eclipse menus do : File, Switch Workspace, Other - then browse to your newly created folder and click

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should set the Android SDK for new workspace of eclipse again. You just need to click windows/preference/android and set SDK location, then click "apply" button.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I moved my entire Eclipse installation directory but the workspace was still getting created in the older location only. And worst there was no option to select the Workspace directory in the Window->Options->Workspace menu.

To change the workspace location in Eclipse do this. Goto ECLIPSE_HOME\configuration.settings directory, edit the org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs file and change the RECENT_WORKSPACES value to the desired location.

If you want that Eclipse prompts you to select workspace when you start it, change the SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG value to true.

And you are done!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advice you to create your own start script. When you're on Windows something like

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem set your Java settings here (JAVA_HOME and PATH) - setjava is a private script I use
rem call setjava 1.7 -arch x86_64

set ADT_HOME=D:\lang\android\adt-bundle
set ADT_EXEC=%ADT_HOME%\eclipse\eclipse.exe

set WORKSPACE_HOME=%~dp0

start "ADT" /MIN %ADT_EXEC% -data %WORKSPACE_HOME% -showlocation -clean -vmargs -Xmx2048M

endlocal
```